# Powershell: hashtable content not displayed within a function

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a function to which I pass a hashtable. Within the function I want to 1) Display text on-screen via Write-Host; 2) display the contents of the hashtable one time -- to provide the usual two-column "Name" / "Value" hashtable display. 3) Have the function return `$true` or `$false`.

```
MyFunction $MyHashTable
```

Within the function:

```
param (
    [hashtable]$TheHashTable
)
#  Sundry things here and then:
write-host "Some information to display on-screen`n"
#  and then:
$TheHashTable
```

The expected result of the latter is something like:

```
Some information to display on-screen

Name    Value
----    -----
a       b
c       d
```

And eventually:

```
return $true #  If what I'm doing worked; otherwise, $false
```

If I call the function as shown above, I see text displayed via `Write-Host` on-screen, plus the two-column display of the hashtable's contents -- **and** the text `True` or `False` on-screen, depending on what the function returns.

If I call it this way:

```
$myResult = MyFunction $MyHashTable
```

... I capture the return value of the function in `$myResult` -- but the display of the hash table's content is *suppressed*. It is also suppressed if I do this:

```
if ( (MyFunction $MyHashTable) -eq $true ) {
    #   do something
} else {
    #   do something different
}
```

Is there a way to

1. Ensure the display of hashtable content, no matter how the function is called;
2. In any case, *suppress* the on-screen display of `True` and `False` when the `Return` statement is executed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any output generated by your function will be sent down the pipeline. This is exactly what happens when you write:

```
$TheHashTable
```

If you want to write this value to the screen instead of the pipeline you should also use `Write-Host` like you do earlier in the example like so:

```
Write-Host $TheHastTable
```

However using the code above you will probably get something like the following output:

```
PS>$table = @{ "test"="fred";"barney"="wilma"}
PS> write-host $table
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

Apparently `Write-Host` does not apply the formatting you expect, this can be fixed by using `Out-String` like so:

```
PS> $table | Out-String | Write-Host
```

resulting in:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
barney                         wilma
test                           fred
```

Comment: Works just as advertised. Thanks kindly. I'm really starting to love this web site. :)